# How do I store sensitive user specific data in my Django application?

Tags: python, django

Users in my Django application all have unique API keys from a third-party service. The feature in my application that I'm building requires the retrieval of the api key with respect to the current user.

What are the best practises here and best options?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your API keys, and store it on Database.

This [django library](https://github.com/jazzband/django-fernet-encrypted-fields) (maintained by Jazzband) can help you with this.

```py
from encrypted_fields.fields import EncryptedTextField

class API_key(models.Model):
    key = EncryptedTextField()
```

#### Note:

1. Encryption and decryption is done on django application not on database server as a result certain features such as filtering may not work as expected
2. the encrypted fields shouldn't be  `indexed`,  `primary key` or have `unique` constraint.